# How would add a tab at the beginning of my for loop in python?

Tags: python

```
for i in range(len(board)):
    print (i, end="")
print ()
```

#0123

I want to print it with a space at the beginning but not affected the rest of the loop:

#" "0123

but I don't really know how to go about it.

Comment: Can you add your whole code? What is in the variable `board`?

Comment: put `print(' ', end='')` before loop?

Comment: Why don't you use `print(f" {i}")`?

Comment: You can put `print ("\t", end="")` just before the loop.

Comment: Please reformat it and add it to the question itself

Comment: Thanks @AskoldIlvento that was all I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if` statement, since you know that the first number is 0::

```
for i in range(len(board)):
    if i == 0:
        print('\t' + str(i), end = "")
    else:
        print (i, end="")
```

Or, as suggested in the comments, just print the `\t` before you even enter the loop.

Comment: print (" ", end="") was excatly what I needed but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you want a blank line before the for loop just do `print("\n")` That will make it print a blank line. Alternatively you could add a flag to your for loop. something like

```
for i in range(len(board)):
  if i == 0:
    print("")
  print(i)
```

This may make it print vertically in a column though so you just need to remove the \n operator

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(board)):
    print ((i if i != 0 else ' '+str(i)), end="")
print ()
```

Comment: Please explain why this words; don't just post code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just do it all in one go, without loop and without extra `print()` afterwards:

```
>>> print(' ', *range(len(board)), sep='')
 0123
```